Express + Typescript how to improve server startup time?
All the time measurements I'm talking here are about the dev server started with nodemon app.ts
First of all, here is my compiler config (tsconfig.json):
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


My dev server used to take ~30s to start. I realized I had mixed up require and import because i'm kind of new to web dev and doesn't know the history. After some research, I read somewhere that require does caching of full modules (can't import part of it as with import) while import does full fresh import everytime.
I have 2 problems with that:
Problem 1
My measurements after switching all the require for import seem to suggest otherwise
back-cdlt_1  | [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
back-cdlt_1  | [nodemon] starting `ts-node app.ts`
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 2.2  s | TOTAL: 2.2  s | Node.js started, runnning app.ts
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 168 ms | TOTAL: 2.4  s | Middlewares loaded
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 1.8  s | TOTAL: 4.2  s | Route POST '/api/user/password' added
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 197 ms | TOTAL: 4.4  s | Route POST '/api/user/login' added
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 31  ms | TOTAL: 4.4  s | Route PUT '/api/user-password' added
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 46  ms | TOTAL: 4.5  s | Route POST '/api/user' added
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 98  ms | TOTAL: 4.6  s | Route PUT '/api/user/:id/permissions' added
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 36  ms | TOTAL: 4.6  s | Route PUT '/api/user/:id/status' added
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 34  ms | TOTAL: 4.6  s | Route PUT '/api/user/:id' added
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 29  ms | TOTAL: 4.7  s | Route GET '/api/users' added
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 17  ms | TOTAL: 4.7  s | Route GET '/api/user/:id/permissions' added
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 35  ms | TOTAL: 4.7  s | Route POST '/api/supplier' added
back-cdlt_1  | TIME: 31  ms | TOTAL: 4.7  s | Route DELETE '/api/supplier/:id' added

All the routes have very similar imports since they almost all import my custom Route class, the database object, the query builder, the auth module and so on...
It does look like the first route takes for 70% of the time, the seconde one 20%, and the rest are very fast to load. Is it only the warm-up time of the V8 engine I heard about or a caching mechanism in import ?
Problem 2
When I tried to use require I didn't mention to import the types for my dependencies. Is require unusable with Typescript? I heard ES5/ES6 syntax should be prefered, is require becoming deprecated and import should be prefered anyway ?
6s start-up is good but can I do better ?
I'm learning and using Angular for my front-end, and the stack used in the default config has either a bundler or some hot-reloading feature (I'm not sure exactly, still new to web dev). When I change a file, I get an instant server reload because only this file is recompiled. Can I achieve such a feature with my express back-end ?
Does I have to run as ES5 or ES6 and not CommonJS for it ? I hope not because I get all sorts of Cannot use import statement outside a module errors when I try :s
Do you have any other ideas to improve start-up time ? Is 6s acceptable or too much ? I have ~50 routes imported, all in different files.
